# How can validate an array of a class with its validations?

Tags: java, bean-validation

Hi I have the next code:

```
public class PkData{
    @NotNull
    Private String stringA;
    ...
}

public class A{
    private PkData pkData = new PkData();

    @NotNull
    private Integer sequenceNumberA;

    @NotNull
    Private String stringA;

    @NotNull
    Private String stringB;
...
}

public class B{
    @NotNull
    private A a;
...
}
```

When call `Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validate(B);`

The validator only return B errors, and not sub clases errors like A.stringA as not null.

How can do get these validations.

And if B be a B[] how can do it?

Any idea? thanks

Comment: It really really is unclear what you are talking about. Please consider rewriting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `@Valid`annotation on `private A a;` in class `B`

Answer (score 1):

You can create validate methods in each Class `A` and class `PkData` which will check the value of each private fields present in them and validate those values.